# In iPad Pages, how to make the text in a cell of a table vertical?

Tags: ipad, pages

In iPad pages, how to make text in a cell of a table vertical?

The information on the Internet is not sufficient. They point to part that can’t be find on iPad Pages, or maybe I cannot find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical text in a table cell is currently not possible to set on Pages for iOS, iPadOS or web, only on macOS.

You can provide feedback to Apple at https://www.apple.com/feedback/pages-ios-ipados.html.

Comment: Any way around it, though?